# Calculate marginal effects of probit model with categorial data

Tags: r, glm, margins, marginal-effects

So my example data looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plm)
library(car)
library(margins)
test <- structure(list(period = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8), indicator = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

In the next step I create different categories for the `period`variable

```
test$factor_period <-car::recode(test$period,"0:2='<2';3:5='3-5';6='6';7='7';8='8';9='9';10='10';11='11';12:44='>12'")
```

I am now calculating a probit model.

```
model_time <- glm(indicator ~ factor_period, family = binomial(link = "probit"), data = test)
```

So far so good. Now I am trying do determine the marginal effect of `factor_period` on `indicator` at `factor_period = "8"`like this:

```
res_time <- summary(margins(model = model_time, at = list(factor_period = "8"), data = test))
```

This returns the error message:

```
Error in attributes(.Data) <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) : 
      'names'[1] attribute must be the same length as the vector[0]
```

It seems like categorizing the `period` data is the problem. Without the `at`argurment, the `margins`command works just fine...Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** By releveling `factor_period` to "8" you can avoid the `at`command in the `margins`operator and therefore calculate all marginal effects.

```
test$factor_period<-relevel(as.factor(test$factor_period), ref="8")
```